# Browser window size on macOS < 500px

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, safari, size

Hellooo,

normally it's not possible to make the browser size smaller than 500px on macOS. Is there a way to hack this?

I want to check how my website would look if the browser size is 100px wide.

Thanks.

Love

Answer (score 0):

Responsive design mode will go all the way down to 50px in width in Chrome and Firefox (75px for Safari).

Chrome: "Toggle device toolbar" (button in the upper left of devtools) and select Responsive.

Firefox: Tools > Web Developer > Responsive Design Mode (or, button in the upper right of devtools).

Safari: Develop > Enter Responsive Design Mode